# GeoServer printing module - Error while generating PDF: "Unknown method: /create.json" and "Unknown method: /create.json"

Tags: geoserver, printing

I take my first steps with the GeoServer Printing module.

I installed it with this guide: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/printing/index.html

So far it worked:

1. The print module configuration file in `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/printing/config.yaml` is created.
2. I can see the parameters in `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json`

Then I entered the IP address of my geoserver in the file `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/printing/config.yaml` (See attached file below) and restarted the geoserver.

Now I expected that I can open the URLs `http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/create.json` and `http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf` in a browser. I tried it on the GeoServer itselfs and form an other machine in the network.

In the case of

```
http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf
```

I see the message

```
Error while generating PDF:
Missing 'spec' parameter
```

and in the case of

```
http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/create.json
```

I see the message

```
Error while generating PDF:
Unknown method: /create.json
```

config.yaml

```
#===========================================================================
# allowed DPIs
#===========================================================================
dpis: [75, 150, 300]

#===========================================================================
# the allowed scales
#===========================================================================
scales:
  - 25000
  - 50000
  - 100000
  - 200000
  - 500000
  - 1000000
  - 2000000
  - 4000000

#===========================================================================
# the list of allowed hosts
#===========================================================================
hosts:
  - !localMatch
    dummy: true
  - !ipMatch
    ip: www.camptocamp.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.opengeo.org
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: terraservice.net
    port: 80
  - !dnsMatch
    host: sigma.openplans.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: demo.mapfish.org
  - !dnsMatch
    host: 172.16.206.128
    port: 8080

layouts:
  Legal:
    mainPage:
      pageSize: LEGAL
      items:
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
  #===========================================================================
  A4 portrait:
  #===========================================================================
    metaData:
#      title: '${mapTitle}'
      author: 'MapFish print module'
      subject: 'Simple layout'
      keywords: 'map,print'
      creator: 'MapFish'

    titlePage:
      pageSize: A4
      items:
        - !text
          spacingAfter: 150
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 40
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          text: '${layout}'
        - !image
          maxWidth: 160
          maxHeight: 160
          spacingAfter: 100
          align: center
          url: http://trac.mapfish.org/trac/mapfish/attachment/ticket/3/logo_v8_sphere.svg?format=raw

      footer: &commonFooter
        height: 30
        items:
          - !columns
            config:
              cells:
                - paddingBottom: 5   
            items:
              - !text
                backgroundColor: #FF0000
                align: left
                text: a red box
              - !text
                align: right
                text: 'Page ${pageNum}'
              - !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 100
                maxHeight: 30
                spacingAfter: 200
                url: 'http://geoserver.org/img/geoserver-logo.png'

    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    mainPage:
      pageSize: A4
      rotation: true
#      header:
#        height: 50
#        items:
#          - !text
#            font: Helvetica
#            fontSize: 30
#            align: right
#            text: '${layout}'
      items:
        - !text
          text: '${mapTitle}'
          fontSize: 30
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !map
          spacingAfter: 30
          width: 440
          height: 483
        - !columns
          # columns can have an absolute position. In that case, they need the 3 following fields:
          absoluteX: 410
          absoluteY: 310
          width: 100
          items:
            - !scalebar
              type: bar
              maxSize: 100
              barBgColor: white
              fontSize: 8
              align: right
        - !text
          text: '${comment}'
          spacingAfter: 30
        - !attributes
          source: data
          spacingAfter: 30
          columnDefs:
            id:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: ID
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !text
                text: '${id}'
            name:
              columnWeight: 5
              header: !text
                text: Name
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !columns
                config:
                  cells:
                    - backgroundColor: '${nameBackgroundColor}'
                      borderWidth: 1
                      borderColor: '${nameBorderColor}'
                items:
                  - !text
                    text: '${name}'
            icon:
              columnWeight: 2
              header: !text
                text: Symbol
                backgroundColor: #A0A0A0
              cell: !image
                align: center
                maxWidth: 15
                maxHeight: 15
                url: 'http://www.mapfish.org/svn/mapfish/trunk/MapFish/client/mfbase/mapfish/img/${icon}.png'
        - !text
          font: Helvetica
          fontSize: 9
          align: right
          text: '1:${scale} ${now MM.dd.yyyy}'
      footer: *commonFooter
```

info.json

```
{"scales":[{"name":"1:25.000","value":"25000.0"},{"name":"1:50.000","value":"50000.0"},{"name":"1:100.000","value":"100000.0"},{"name":"1:200.000","value":"200000.0"},{"name":"1:500.000","value":"500000.0"},{"name":"1:1.000.000","value":"1000000.0"},{"name":"1:2.000.000","value":"2000000.0"},{"name":"1:4.000.000","value":"4000000.0"}],"dpis":[{"name":"75","value":"75"},{"name":"150","value":"150"},{"name":"300","value":"300"}],"outputFormats":[{"name":"pdf"}],"layouts":[{"name":"A4 portrait","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":true},{"name":"Legal","map":{"width":440,"height":483},"rotation":false}],"printURL":"http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/print.pdf","createURL":"http://172.16.206.128:8080/geoserver/pdf/create.json"}
```

Comment: Can you look at the following link http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GS-2-5-print-problem-after-tomcat-update-Print-url-400-Bad-Request-td5304683.html

Comment: I looked at your link. But I do not understand how this helps me.

Comment: Basically when it tells you the spec  is missing you need to include it in the url https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/printing/protocol.html

Comment: Could you please help me with this url thing. How am i supposed to pass the authkey in the url: 'http://localhost:8080/print/print.pdf'